# SOQL returning 0 rows for multi picklist values

Tags: apex

```
String Accounttype = 'College/University;State/Local Government';

list<string> lstacctype = Accounttype.split(';'); 

    String slist = '';

   for (String s1: lstacctype) {

   slist += '\'' + s1 + '\',';

   }

   slist = slist.substring (0,slist.length() -1);

[select Id,Country__c FROM User_Mapping_Location__c WHERE State_Province__c =null and City__c = null and User__c =: userId and Sales_Rep_Configuration__r.Account_type__C includes (:slist )]
```

**Please help where am i doing wrong,even the debug statement of the 'slist' is returning values in Correct format**

**15:54:47:059 USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|'College/University','State/Local Government'**

Comment: are you looking for partial matches with those strings ? if not, after you split the values into an Array, you can simply use IN clause and pass the array instead of using INCLUDES..

Comment: i changed it to [select Id,Country__c FROM User_Mapping_Location__c WHERE State_Province__c =null and City__c = null and User__c =: userId and Sales_Rep_Configuration__r.Account_type__C in :lstacctype  ] **but still no results,results are still 0,so i checked again passing values manually its working fine,SO donno why its not returning results**

Answer (score 0):

Your includes parameter need to be semicolon separated. see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000211744&type=1) below will give you the result. What you are getting in the string you are preparing it needs to be like below

```
String Accounttype = '\'College/University\',\'State/Local Government\'';
[select Id,Country__c FROM User_Mapping_Location__c WHERE State_Province__c =null and City__c = null and User__c =: userId and Sales_Rep_Configuration__r.Account_type__C includes :Accounttype ];
```

Comment: no @avijit still the same result

Comment: When i see the debug log its giving the results in the format SOQL query expects 'A' , 'B' for the Variable ,for some its still not returning any results